# Is there a XML meta language for expressing complex search queries?

Tags: xml, search, metaprogramming

during the past couple of years a lot of our internal APIs for modifying and searching our database have become more and more entangled with the specific needs and application logic of the front ends that they power. To counter that trend we've decided to gradually move those APIs to web services with stable and concisely specified interfaces. Another reason for this step is that the APIs were initially designed for traditional websites while they are now more and more being used by AJAX applications, iPhone apps, external customers an so on.

While working out the details of this process we've realized that one of the major functionalities that we plan on providing are fairly complex searches through various types of resources like, for example, people, documents and locations.

Now, it is obvious that the details of a search largely depend on the search space. There are, however, a lot of meta-concepts that are universal. For instance, logical operators connecting search predicates and a hierarchical structure (braces) and precedence rules for these operations; range queries for numeric values, regular expression matching for strings, and so on. Given these concepts, XML immediately comes to mind as an adequate representation for a query (so do DSLs, but I think that is too big of a gun in our case).

So my question is this: is there an XML meta language on which we can base our own, domain-specific dialect for expression such queries? Or are there other possibilities which have so far not crossed our minds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following schema is widely used in GIS world:

- http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/1.1.0/

Here's an example:

```
  <ogc:Filter xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
        <ogc:PropertyName>isoap:CreationDate</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>2007-07-31</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
      <ogc:Or>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>isoap:Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>service</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>isoap:Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>application</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>isoap:Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>dataset</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Or>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

This can be processed in relational databases as well as document-oriented databases or with full-text indexing like Lucene.

Comment: Looks interesting. Although, at first glance, it looks like it is a very basic spec. (Which isn't a bad thing per se, but it looks like it is so basic that using it instead of reinventing it tailored to our needs wouldn't really save us all that much work.)

Answer (score 1):

There's [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) which can be extended with your own functions, etc., but that's not wholly XML-based (it works *with* XML, but is not itself XML).

Comment: Also note that anything powerful enough to support interesting queries is probably also going to be powerful enough to cause real problems if untrusted users write queries. It's time for you to think about your security models.

Comment: Point taken. A security model is of course also on our to-do list. I know about XQuery, but I am not sure how applicable it is in this case because at some point we'll have to map the query to SQL in one way or another. It seems to me that using XPath may not be the ideal choice here (but I'm not really an expert on the subject, so feel free to elaborate!).

Comment: Well, XQuery is a bit like SQL for XML. :-) It's very capable indeed, and builds on top of XPath. But I've not a lot of personal experience with using it in deployment; I was planning to, but then my work went sideways off in a different direction (such is life).

Comment: I'm aware of other query languages too, but SQL, XQuery and SPARQL are the only ones I'd actually recommend (for relational, hierarchic and linked data respectively, and in the latter two cases only if a good implementation can be found; it's well known that there are good SQL implementations so I don't need to qualify that…)

Comment: Hm. Maybe building an SQL wrapper around an SQL query isn't really as useful as it sounds :)

Comment: @n3rd: If you want an XML vocabulary there is also [XQueryX](http://www.w3.org/TR/xqueryx/)

Comment: @Alejandro: Hmm, didn't know about that. Shows how much out of date I am in this area. :-)